# I2C support in new kernels seems to be broken

Tags: linux-kernel, i2c

Can anybody tell me what's the difference in supporting I2C between kernels until and after 3.10 version?

Looks like after 3.10 something changed but I can't realize what exactly. I'm working on Intel Core-i5 2500k CPU with integrated video and am using ddccontrol tool to change brightness on my monitor. But if on kernel 3.2.32 I can do that, since 3.10.5 I2C support seems to be broken.

I don't know what exactly changed, but there are outputs from old and new kernels (i2cdetect -l):
3.2.32: http://pastebin.com/SqDPcwS9
3.10.5: http://pastebin.com/YCTmX90m

If on 3.2.32 I was able to use i2c-4 device to control my monitor, then on 3.10.5 list of i2c devices is shorter, and I don't see any GPIO buses (or what does it mean). On 3.10.5 system detects only monitor on i2c-1 but says that there is no support of DDC/CI on that device (http://pastebin.com/vZ4bALmt). For 3.2.32 everything is OK: http://pastebin.com/QL0fAZVC

Maybe I don't know something, e.g. some new config option have been added/changed in kernel.

Seems I'm not alone in my trouble - there are a lot of questions about I2C and ddccontrol around the web, but there are still no answer.

Need your help, really...

Thanks!

---

UPD: on kernel 3.7 I've watched the same behavior as on 3.10, so, the breakage isn't at 3.10 but a bit earlier

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but I think this has been fixed in commit [59b016fe8fe83920e8717163289e61ab8e327b90](http://o.cs.uvic.ca:20810/perl/cid.pl?cid=59b016fe8fe83920e8717163289e61ab8e327b90) the 17.10.2013

Can you try a more recent kernel (3.12) ?